# What are the age limits for an Agamic initiation? Can a very old person be initiated as well?

Tags: agamas, tantra, initiation

For the Vedic initiation (the Upanayana) the prescribed ages(when to perform the initiation) are given in various scriptures like the Manu Smriti etc. And, the age limits till which the disciples can be initiated are also given.

> 2.36. In the eighth year after conception, one should perform the initiation (upanayana) of a Brahmana, in the eleventh after conception
> (that) of a Kshatriya, but in the twelfth that of a Vaisya.
>
> 2.38. The (time for the) Savitri (initiation) of a Brahmana does not pass until the completion of the sixteenth year (after conception), of
> a Kshatriya until the completion of the twenty-second, and of a Vaisya
> until the completion of the twenty-fourth.

I am looking to know about similar (upper and lower) age limits (if any exist at all) for the Tantric/Agamic initiation.

Can a very old person be initiated as per the Tantras? Similarly at what age a person becomes qualified for a Tantric initiation?

Comment: One can initiate into Agamas as long as one has sexual power as it is a sign of latent power hidden below Muladhaar. About reference - Can't give reference(s). It is secret. can't reveal secret knowledge to everyone.

Comment: Did you find answer to this question? If yes! Can you please post it, otherwise my bounty will be wasted :D

Comment: No I still don't know the answer. @TheLittleNaruto